# Visual Studio 2017 and dotnet run command line fails

Tags: visual-studio-2017, dotnet-cli

Using Visual Studio 2017RC for an ASP.NET Core project the `project.json` file is converted to an `MyApplication.csproj` file.

However, the `dotnet run` command line now throws an error:

> C:\Projects\MyApplication(1,0): error DOTNET1017: Project file does not exist 'C:\Projects\MyApplication\project.json'.

Is `dotnet` missing an update to handle `.csproj`? Or should I be using a different command line to run it outside Visual Studio?

Comment: Can you check what the SDK version is in your global.json file (Root of your solution) if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently. I had to remove all the older versions of .NET Core and reinstall the latest version. Once I did that, it started working again.